# Fastest Technology and best performance for a Web Bot

Tags: performance, selenium, phantomjs, htmlunit, bots

I'm trying to build a web bot, and I was researching about the fastest technologies available. 
After reading a lot, I saw the fastest technologies are headless browsers.
PhantomJS and HtmlUnit is what I found to be the fastest ones.

PhantomJS it seems it has good support for javascript, and HtmlUnit seems it does not, on the other hand HtmlUnit is a bit faster.

In terms or performance (CPU and Memory usage) I didn't found anything about it.

Do you guys know any other technology?

I'm trying to build a really fast bot to do a certain flow. And I will run in parallel this flow, so having multiple threads doing the same thing. Ideally I wanna choose a technology that is fast on navigating, but that is also light in order to allow me to open as many threads as possible.

Comment: Benchmark your use case.  If you have lots of parallel processing, keep an eye on memory use as well as CPU use.

Comment: "to do a certain flow" is pretty darn broad. Just for plain webscraping, Selenium is the exact **wrong** choice.